# json object returning undefined [nodejs, fs]

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, fs

I have a script that should list some data that is an object accessed through var['messages'] etc. My code is as followed

```
var lines = fs.readFileSync(chattxt, 'utf8');
    var lines = lines.split("\n");
    var maxlines = 10;
    if (lines.length < 10) maxlines = lines.length-1;

    for (var i = (lines.length - maxlines); i<(lines.length)-1; i++){
        socket.emit('message', { message: lines['message'] });
        console.log(lines['message']);
    }
```

But i am not sure why it is just logging undefined into the console, an example of the lines is

```
{"message":"<div>test</div>"}
```

Im very confused why its outputting undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand ever line is not a javascript object. It just string. You need to convert to Javascript object like-

```
for (var i = (lines.length - maxlines); i<(lines.length)-1; i++){
        var msg = JSON.parse(lines[i]); 
        socket.emit('message', { message: msg.message });
        console.log(msg);
    }
```